# Angularjs http get from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I want to get List of employees, after clicking on button `Get Data`. But JS script does not invoke `public JsonResult GetData`.

1. Why js do not invoke `public JsonResult GetData` where is mistake?
2. How to pass argument in 'public JsonResult GetData(int id)'?

HomeController:

```
namespace AngularJS.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetData(int id)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee{Name="Jhon"});
        employees.Add(new Employee{Name="Rick"});
        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

MyScript.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("calendarDemo", function($scope) {
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.getData = function () {

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetData' }).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //$scope.Employees = [{ name: 'Jhon' }, { name: 'Rick' }];
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert('error');
});

}
});
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/MyScript.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/style.less">
<script src="~/Scripts/less-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <li ng-repeat="employee in Employees">
        {{employee.name}}
    </li>
<button ng-click="getData()">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: can you show the web api routing config?

Comment: from where you are loading `angular.js`? I can't see it.

Comment: Have you tried calling the URL directly from the browser's address bar? Does it work? If you set a breakpoint at the mvc action, does it get hit?

Comment: @fikkatra this is a Controller, not an ApiController.  It would be the regular routing, not the web api routing.

Comment: Remove the parameter from webmethod and then use same $http call, if it invokes the webmethod it means you need to pass the parameter too. to pass parameter use third parameter of $http object.

Comment: @PankajParkar, angular.js loading in _Layout.cshtml it's working well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you kept the default routing config in MVC, try this:

```
$scope.getData = function (id) {
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetData/' + id }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.Employees = [{ name: 'Jhon' }, { name: 'Rick' }];
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');
        });
};
```

and pass the id to the `getData` function from the view.

Answer (score 1):

You should be pass it as parameter in $http get call

```
$http({ method: 'GET', url: '/Home/GetData', params: { id: id } })
```

Comment: This will attach the id as a query parameter. This will work, because MVC will try to find the id in the query string if it can't be found within the url. However, this will result in a different url: /Home/GetData?id=123 instead of /Home/GetData/123 . Depending on which url is preferred, use params or attach the id directly to the url

Comment: @fikkatra I know.. if default route is set correctly like you said it should be like you are suggesting.. but in that case above will obviously work..

Comment: Exactly. I was just trying to help the OP make a sensible choice between our solutions.

Comment: @fikkatra If you ask me perticularly, then I would rather use the format you suggested in WebAPI +1 yours..